# convert html form cloumn array to row php

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I have an html form which which has multiple textarea and its values are coming from database.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($record)){
echo "<tr class='item-row'>";
echo "<td>" .$startSrno. "</td>";
echo "<td class='item-name'> <div class='delete-wpr'><textarea name='productName[]'>".$row['name']."</textarea></div></td>";
echo "<td>".$row['pkgsize']."</td>";
echo "<td><textarea class='savings' name='saving[]'>".$row['savings']."</textarea></td>";
echo "<td><textarea class='mrp' name='mrp[]'>".$row['MRP']."</textarea></td>";
echo "<td><textarea class='qty' name='qty[]'>1</textarea></td>";
echo "<td><textarea class='cost' name='saleprice[]'>".$row['saleprice']."</textarea></td>";
echo "<td><textarea class='price' name='total[]'>".$row['saleprice'] * '1'."</textarea></td>";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="productId[]" value="'.$row['id']. '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pkgsize[]" value="'.$row['pkgsize']. '">';
echo "</tr>";
$startSrno++;

}
```

now when i submit this form i get these arrays of form which has multiple values but they are in column format where as i need it in row form:

### By doing this (using implode function ()) i get below output:

```
$id = implode(',',$_POST['productId']);<br/>
$name = implode(',',$_POST['productName']);
$saving = implode(',',$_POST['saving']);
$qty = implode(',',$_POST['qty']);
$pkgsize = implode(',',$_POST['pkgsize']);
$mrp = implode(',',$_POST['mrp']);
$saleprice = implode(',',$_POST['saleprice']);
$total = implode(',',$_POST['total']);
```

### Current Output by using echo e.g. echo $name == (Boost,Olay):

```
Boost,Olay,Bournvita (Name)
45,35,20 (Savings)
2,3,5 (qty)
500gm,20ml,1kg(pkgsize)
120,70,320(mrp)
75,35,300(saleprice)
150,105,1500(total)
```

### But i want output in below stated (row) format to use directly in insert query:

```
(Boost,45,2,500gm,120,75,150),(Olay,35,3,20ml,120,35,105),(Bournvita,20,5,1kg,300,75,1500)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a for-loop for that. Provided you already validated that data and made sure no empty 'cell' was passed in.

```
$products = '(' . $name[0] .  ',' . $saving[0] . ',' . $qty[0] . ',' . $pkgsize[0] . ',' . $mrp[0] . ',' . $saleprice[0] . ',' . $total[0] . ')';

for($i = 1; $i < count($id); $i++)
    $products = ',(' . $name[i] .  ',' . $saving[i] . ',' . $qty[i] . ',' . $pkgsize[i] . ',' . $mrp[i] . ',' . $saleprice[i] . ',' . $total[i] . ')';
```

My PHP skills may not be up to date and it probably could be done better, but I'd say this should work.

Comment: Didn't work the output is :  (B,40,1,500g,320,280,280)

Answer (score 0):

```
$b = '';
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['productId']); $i++) {
  $a = array(
   //$_POST['productId'][$i],
   $_POST['productName'][$i],
   $_POST['saving'][$i],
   $_POST['qty'][$i],
   $_POST['pkgsize'][$i],
   $_POST['mrp'][$i],
   $_POST['saleprice'][$i],
   $_POST['total'][$i]
  );
  if ($b != '') $b .= ',';
  $b = '('.implode(',',$a).')';
}
echo $b;
```

Comment: Nope the output is :

Comment: (Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array)

Comment: @Gravirel Also making it like this :       implode(',',$_POST['productName']),
       implode(',',$_POST['saving']),  
       implode(',',$_POST['qty']),  
       implode(',',$_POST['pkgsize']),  
       implode(',',$_POST['mrp']),  
       implode(',',$_POST['saleprice']),  
       implode(',',$_POST['total'])  out put is this :(Boost,Olay,40,5,1,1,500g,20g,320,27,280,22,280,22)

Comment: try now, I forgot the [$i]

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks Gravirel for your help, finally did it with a bit or Trial and Error.

```
$oddArray = array();
$evenArray = array();

$insertValues = '';

for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['productId']); $i++) {
  if ($i % 2 == 0) {
      //echo $i."<br/>";
      $insertValues .= '(';
      $evenArray = array(
       //$_POST['productId'][$i],
       '\''.$_POST['productName'][$i].'\'',
       $_POST['saving'][$i],
       $_POST['qty'][$i],
       '\''.$_POST['pkgsize'][$i].'\'',
       $_POST['mrp'][$i],
       $_POST['saleprice'][$i],
       $_POST['total'][$i]
      );
      $insertValues .= implode(',',$evenArray);
      $insertValues .= '),';
  }else{
      //echo $i."<br/>";

      $insertValues .= '(';
      $oddArray = array(
       //$_POST['productId'][$i],
       '\''.$_POST['productName'][$i].'\'',
       $_POST['saving'][$i],
       $_POST['qty'][$i],
       '\''.$_POST['pkgsize'][$i].'\'',
       $_POST['mrp'][$i],
       $_POST['saleprice'][$i],
       $_POST['total'][$i]
      );
      $insertValues .= implode(',',$oddArray);
      $insertValues .= '),';
  }
 }

$insertValuesTrim = rtrim($insertValues,',');
```

### Output : ('Boost',45,2,'500gm',120,75,150),('Olay',35,3,'20ml',120,35,105),('Bournvita',20,5,'1kg',300,75,1500)